# How to combine 2 IFS formulas with several conditions into one

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to combine 2 IFS formulas with some conditions into just one but I am missing something.
[image]

Both formulas below:

Reit Tax:

```
=IF(AND(H2>10,C2="Reit"),CONCAT("± $ ",ROUND(H2*0.2,0)),"No")
```

Stock Tax:

```
=IF(AND(F2>20000,H2>0,C2="Stock"),CONCAT("± $ ",ROUND(H2*0.15,0)),"No")
```

I'm just failing in combining them into one. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
=IFS(AND(H2>10,C2="Reit"),CONCAT("± $ ",ROUND(H2*0.2,0)), AND(F2>20000,H2>0,C2="Stock"),CONCAT("± $ ",ROUND(H2*0.15,0), "No"))
```

If you have any idea on what I'm missing, please help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to balance the brackets after the final CONCAT and add a true value to force the "No" condition if neither of the two previous conditions is satisfied:

```
=IFS(AND(H2>10,C2="Reit"),CONCAT("± $ ",ROUND(H2*0.2,0)), AND(F2>20000,H2>0,C2="Stock"),CONCAT("± $ ",ROUND(H2*0.15,0)),TRUE, "No")
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work. The error message is: Wrong number of arguments to CONCAT. Expected 2 arguments, but got 4 arguments.

Comment: Apologies, I copied the wrong version of the formula (although if you look closely you can see it entered correctly in the screenshot. If you look _very_ closely you can see that I tested it in Excel, not Google Sheets, but it works in either).